# Passing search and filter parameters between Components

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am trying to implement breadcrum functionality in my application using Blazor.
My requirements are:

1. Search page - Click search: shows list of items using card
2. I have a filter box to filter data . e.g posted date, range
3. When I select a single item, it should go the detail page. On the detail page I should see a breadcrum like - Home -> View -> Detail
4. So when I click on the View breadcrum item it should take me back to view page with the previous search parameters and filters selected

I know how to pass single parameters between components but little confuse how can I pass multiple parameters to parent and again back to child component. Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I don't have the code yet, have to implement it. I just want to know how can I implement it using Blazor Parameters or State management.